# Game Center localPlayer always authenticated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, game-center

I'm trying to detect whether the local player authentication is working or not and it appears that I always get a positive result.

Here is the code I am using:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)authenticateLocalPlayer 
{
    NSLog(@"Authenticating local player %@ (%d)", ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated? @"YES":@"NO"), [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated);
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
        [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            [self callDelegateOnMainThread:@selector(authenticationChanged:) 
                                   withArg:nil 
                                     error:error];
        }];
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)authenticationChanged:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error authenticating local player: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    NSLog(@"Authentication changed %@ (%d)", ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated? @"YES":@"NO"), [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated);
}
```

I tested this code while disconnected from the network and here is the trace output:

```
2010-12-13 13:20:59.799 LittleScreams[954:307] Authenticating local player NO (0)
2010-12-13 13:21:01.616 LittleScreams[954:307] Error authenticating local player: The Internet connection appears to be offline.
2010-12-13 13:21:01.621 LittleScreams[954:307] Authentication changed YES (1)
```

It clearly sees that the connection is offline but is still authenticating the player! Any ideas what's going on? I'm getting the same result on the device and in the simulator.

TIA

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm testing my Game Center functionality and wanted to see what happens when in flight mode. If I was logged in to Game Center before entering flight mode the app will not authorize a player (of course), but when doing a [localPlayer isAuthenticated] I get a YES with the player ID that is logged in to Game Center. Have you found any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't call authenticationChanged manually, take a look at Game Kit Programming Guide and follow the steps, that worked for me.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html

Comment: I'm actually not calling it manually, authenticationChanged gets called by the completion handler. This code is based off the GKTapper example by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html